# Need fix on stopping page reloading after file uploading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm trying to upload files to the server without page refresh. The uploading works but the page reloads after the uploading is done which is not what I wanted. I'm redirecting to an iframe ("myFrame") to stop the page reloading but it appears this doesn't work correctly. What did I do wrong?

HTML

```
<form id="upload" target="myFrame" action="sql/main-pix-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="main-pix" class="hidden" name="main_pix" type="file" onchange="uploadPix()" accept="image/*"/>
  <label class="gi gi-camera mb-0 text-white" for="main-pix" type="button" title="Change Picture"></label>
</form>
<iframe class="hidden" name="myFrame"></iframe>
```

SCRIPT

```
function uploadPix(){
  var form = document.getElementById('upload');
  form.onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'sql/main-pix-upload.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    })
  });
};
```

PHP

```
$account = $_SESSION['account'];
$order = $_SESSION['order'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$pathPix = ('../accounts/'.$account.'/'.$order.'/pix/'.$id.'/');
if(!is_dir($pathPix)){
  mkdir($pathPix, 0777, true);
}

$file_name = $_FILES['main_pix']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['main_pix']['size'];
$extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$new_name = "main-pix.png";
$temp = ($_FILES["main_pix"]["tmp_name"]);
$target_file = ($pathPix.$new_name);

if(0 < $_FILES['main_pix']['error']){
  echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['main_pix']['error'] . '<br>';
}else{
  move_uploaded_file($temp, $target_file);
}
```

Comment: `onchange="uploadPix()"` don't use inline JS. When searching files for a function initialization you're not supposed fo find it in HTML (view). Use `addEventListener` instead. If you *really* want to leave a tip in HTML that some element is bound to some JS stuff than you could use `data-onchange="uploadPix"` and in JS than you can target all your `"[data-onchange]"` elements and retrieve the designated function name like `myOnchangeMethods[this.dataset.onchange]()`

Comment: I took that out and tried everything but it didn't work though.

Answer (score 2):

Either use:

```
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
};
```

or:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

And then you have to make the HTTP-Call by yourself using AJAX.

Comment: Sorry for the noise -> you could show those 7 lines of jQuery to perform such AJAX - might be helpful to OP?!

Comment: I edited based on your comments but it's still not working. Is my code correct? See edits.

Comment: File Uploads do not work with the default jQuery AJAX. You have to use XMLHttpRequest. For more info look here: [MDN: Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files)